# I m getting a new error with this code, that didn't use to happen and I think I deleted something but I am not sure what

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-web-api, methods

I was trying to find an issue and may have modified the code in an unintended way. I am building a webapi, to learn backend, using postman as the front end to complete CRUD operations on a database. I have had issues writing the methods, cause I am new to coding, and when I tried debugging I may have deleted code VS code though was irrelevant in the using statements.

I have spent so much time working on figuring out the methods and chasing issues that I don't even have a clue what I may have deleted in the using statements, so I have no idea where to start.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace L06HandsOn.Models
{
    public class Car
{
    internal static readonly IActionResult ToList;

    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Year {get; set;}
    public string Make {get; set;}
    public string Model {get; set;}
    public int numberOfPassengers {get; set;}


    }
}
```

when I do a dotnet run it says Car.ToList is never assigned to and will always have its default value null. When I run postman, I always get a 500 internal server error, but I was getting that even when it did complete the operations.

EDIT* Here is the controller.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using L06HandsOn.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace L06HandsOn.Controllers
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CarsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly CarsContext _context;

    public CarsController(CarsContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // POST api/Cars
    [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Car car )
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                 _context.Add(car);
                 _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            return CreatedAtRoute("", car.Id, car);
        }
    // GET api/car(all)
    [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok(_context.Cars);
        }
    // GET api/car(by Id)
    [HttpGet("{id:int")]
        public IActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            return Ok(_context.Cars.Find(id));
        }
    //GET api/car(if numberOfPassengers<3)
    [HttpGet("{numberOfPassengers:int}")]
    [Route("Get3")]
        public IActionResult Details2(int numberOfPassenger)
        {
            return Ok(_context.Cars.Find(numberOfPassenger<3));
        }
    //GET api/car(Order by year DESC)
    /* [HttpGet("{year:int}")]
    [Route("YDESC")]
        public IActionResult Details3(int year)
        {
            return Ok(_context.Cars.Find(year.OrderBy.DESC));
        }*/
}
```

}

VT Chiew I only relate it because the error code I get reads

```
Models\Car.cs(9,48): warning CS0649: Field 'Car.ToList' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null [C:\Users\Jon-Michael\Desktop\Programming\CSharp\L06HandsOn\L06HandsOn.csproj]
```

The code it refers to is Models\Car.cs line 9 which is

```
internal static readonly IActionResult ToList;
```

which when hovered over does say IActionResult Car.ToList, that's why In my head it sounds like a using statement is missing that came in with dotnet new web api build out. I'm not afraid to admit I'm new and I'm learning, I don't know the right terminology or anything beyond how it makes sense in my head.

Comment: Were you able to debug when the postman request reaches the web api controller? Showing the controller code might help too (By the way, the warning for `Car.ToList` seems irrelevant to your 500 internal server error.

Comment: _I have spent **so much time** working on figuring out the methods and chasing issues that I don't even have a clue what I **may** have deleted in the using statements, so I have no idea where to start._ And that's why you should you use version control even for trivial things, kids.

Comment: VT Chiew I updated info asked for.